# Why is $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+\frac12x^2}}$ a good approximation for arctan?

Tags: approximation

I played around with the equation

$$
f_{n}(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+nx^2}}
$$

which is the $n$th composition of

$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
$$

Surprising to me, it is a good approximation for $arctan(x)$ when plugging in $n=\frac{1}{2}$.

I tried comparing their Taylor-Series-Expansion but it didn't seem fruitful to me.

Is there maybe a connection to the derivative since

$$arctan'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

If you have any ideas why this is the case I would be glad to hear them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\arctan$ is a function defined in all $\Bbb R$. Are you interested in an approximation for small values of $x$? For big values of $x$? I doubt there is a simpler function that approximate it well in the whole set of real numbers.

Comment: To match 3rd derivative near the origin, you need $n = 2/3\approx 0.67$. To match asymptotic value, you need $n = 4/\pi^2 \approx 0.41$. $n = 1/2$ is a compromise between the two.

Answer (score 1):

There is something interesting in the $\frac 1 2$.

Suppose that you want the best fit of the arctangent, say between $0$ and $t$ using such a model. To find the best $a$, consider the infinite norm
$$\Phi(a,t)=\int_0^t \Big( \tan ^{-1}(x)-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+a x^2}} \Big)^2\,dx$$ which is fully explicit (even if not very nice). This is equivalent to a non linear regression based on an infinite number of data points.

Now, for a given value of $t$, solve for $a$ the equation
$$\frac {\partial \Phi(a,t)}{\partial a}=0$$

A few numbers
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
t & a_{\text{opt}} \\
 5 &  0.520880 \\
 6 &  0.509581 \\
 7 &  0.500667 \\
 8 &  0.493425 \\
 9 &  0.487405 \\
10 &  0.482305 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$